# How to user super() in Django views.py

Tags: django, django-views

I have this class in my views.py

```
class ThreadView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'chat/thread.html'
    form_class = ComposeForm
    success_url = './'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        thread = self.get_object()
        user = self.request.user
        message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")
        print(user, thread, message)
        ChatMessage.objects.create(user=user, thread=thread, message=message)
        print()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I am using python3 **return super().form_valid(form)** and the error says Python version 2.7 does not support this syntax. super() should have arguments in python 2, 
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `super(ThreadView, self).form_valid(form)`

Comment: Also it looks like your code is running with Python 2

Comment: Which is not supported anymore, might want to upgrade to 3